# Upgrading ubuntu having kubuntu-desktop

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu

I have Ubuntu 13.04 with kubuntu-desktop. I removed unity-desktop. Is it safe to upgrade to 13.10? Or should I go for a fresh install?
Edit: My root is only ~15GB. I have /home on a separate partition. I have an ntfs partition for windows and another 15G spare partition (where I used to have another distro, but is now empty)

Comment: Do you have /home on a separate partition from /?

Comment: Yes. I didn't know that was relevant. Adding to question details

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate partitions for /home/ and /, there is no problem.

Download the new version of Kubuntu and put it on a USB stick for extra security. Now do an upgrade to 13.10, and see whether this works. The upgrade will not touch your /home partition in any case.

If all goes well, and you like it, great. Otherwise, with the already-prepared USB stick, do a fresh install. When it comes to partitioning your disk, choose `Manual`, and install only the / partition on the old / partition. You will want to fomat that partition. But tell the installer not to format your old /home partition, just mount it at /home. And you are done.